# What method should use for TCP data transfer

Tags: c#, tcp

I have server(1), which connects to other server(2) which handles some data that my first server(1) cannot handle.

There is only **one connection** , a link between these two servers , you could even call server(2) as client. The amount of stream that is sent between servers are **high**.

**Do you think that using simple TCP listener/client on server(2) which runs on own thread is best way to handle all incoming/outgoing stream ? Remember that there is only one connection so i dont need asynchronous methods/callbacks/concurrency.**

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a single TCP server on server2 that streams both inbound and outbound data over the same connection. If your goal is to always have a single connection, you can setup the server thread to accept only one connection.

It's fairly typical on message based systems/protocols to do this.  The challenge is in what your attempting to do.  If you have multiple clients coming into server1 and they each need data from server2, they may be serialized through the server2 link.

Comment: Server1 has async socket. I created channel.cs class and all the clients are in list on that class, ¨when clients needs to be updated the channel class is asking data from server2.

Only single connection between servers, so when im doing this its proper and is enough?

All the data is serialized and data call is timed.

Comment: It will work, but the scalability depends on how much data you are passing between server2 and server1, and how often your clients need to be updated.

Comment: Okey, i will stick on this and optimize it if needed. Thank you